# Strings aren't being written to new file

Tags: python

I have a list of JSON objects stored as a text file, one JSON object per line (total size is 30 GB), and what I'm trying to do is extract elements from those objects and store them in a new list. Here is my code to do that

```
print("Extracting fingerprints...")
start = time.time()
for jsonObj in open('ctl_records_sample.jsonlines'):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict = json.loads(jsonObj)
    finger = temp_dict['data']['leaf_cert']['fingerprint']
    
    with open("fingerprints.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(finger+"\n")
    
    finger = ""
    

    
end = time.time()
print("Fingerprint extraction finished in" + str(end-start) +"s")
```

Basically, I'm trying to go line-by-line of the original file and write that line's "fingerprint" to the new text file. However, after letting the code run for several seconds, I open up fingerprints.txt and see that only one fingerprint has been written to the file. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. For future debugging questions, we recommend providing a [mre] to help determine what's causing the problem. In this case, thankfully it was pretty obvious, but there are similar situations where the input data could be a factor. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here is the issue:

```
with open("fingerprints.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(finger+"\n")
```

The `"w"` part will truncate file each time it's opened.

You either want to open the file and keep it open throughout your loop, or check that the file exists and if it does open it with `"a"` to append.

Comment: I fixed the info about how the file is destroyed, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Not at all. It is a fair clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the file in each loop iteration, in write mode as per your `w` parameter passed to the `open` function. Therefore it's being overwritten from the beginning.

You can solve it for example with two different approaches:

- You can move your with statement before the `for` loop and everything will work, since it will be writing sequentially over the same file (using the same descriptor and pointer into the file).
- Open the file in append mode each time, what will append your new written content to the end of the file. To do so, replace your `w` with an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `open()` with the `"w"` mode, all the file contents will be deleted. From the Python documentation for the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function:

> `'w'`: open for writing, truncating the file first

I think you are looking to use the `"a"` mode, which *appends* new contents to the end of the file:

> `'a'`: open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

```py
with open("fingerprints.txt", "a", newline="\n") as f:
    f.write(finger)
```

(You can also drop the `+"\n"` to the `f.write()` call by passing the `newline="\n"` argument to `open()`.)

Comment: *"You can also drop the +"\n" to the f.write() call by passing the newline="\n" argument to open()."* -- That's incorrect actually. The `newline` parameter determines *translation*. See the docs: "When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep "os.linesep"). If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string."